# js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, archlinux

I tried to install mean.io stack on an arch linux mini computer (the cubox).
So I install nodejs and mongodb packages.

I retrieve the stack with Git, made an npm install (it was ok) but then:

I get this error after typing 'grunt':

```
[nodemon] v1.2.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node --debug server.js`
debugger listening on port 5858
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

fs.js:439
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/projects/mean/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.map'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:290:15)
    at module.exports (/projects/mean/node_modules/meanio/lib/bootstrap.js:31:27)
    at /projects/mean/node_modules/meanio/lib/mean.js:20:27
    at Config.onPackageRead (/projects/mean/node_modules/meanio/lib/config.js:101:25)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (/projects/mean/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Promise.emit (/projects/mean/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (/projects/mean/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mpromise/lib/promise.js:97:20)
    at Object.cb (/projects/mean/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1146:30)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

node version: v0.10.35
npm version: 2.1.18
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.6

What can I do now?? Any Idea??

Addtional info: I have a warn during npm install:

```
npm WARN cannot run in wd bson@0.2.16 (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0) (wd=/projects/mean/node_modules/bson)
```

Here is builderror.log :

```
cat builderror.log 
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at failNoPython (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:103:14)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:42:11
gyp ERR! stack     at F (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:38:25)
gyp ERR! stack     at E (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:41:29)
gyp ERR! stack     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/which/which.js:52:16
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.14.27-1-ARCH
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /projects/mean/node_modules/bson
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I did installed python (pacman -S python).
python -V -> Python 3.4.2

###### More info:

After spending many time on this, I find something. It seems that 'bower install' can't be launch as root.
And when I launch 'npm install' it calls 'bower install' and fail.

I try launching 'npm install --allow-root', but it doesn't work either.

So I wanted to create a new user in archlinux, but I don't know what group I should add him too.
(I did create one, with some random groups but npm failed with a permission error).

If someone can send me a command to create a user in the good groups so I can test if that solve the problem it would be perfect.

Here is the error I get when launching npm install with a new user belonging to the group 'users':

```
Error: EACCES, open '.bower-registry/bower.herokuapp.com/lookup/angular_d18b8'
Installing module: mean-admin:
rm: could not remove file (code EACCES): packages/contrib/mean-admin/.bowerrc
```

More info:

I reinstall all from the start without being root. Create a user in wheel group. Now I am stuck during npm install here:

```
[tyvain@alarm fast-annonces]$ npm install 
npm WARN package.json express@4.10.6 No README data
npm WARN package.json gridfs-stream@0.5.3 No README data
npm WARN package.json supertest@0.11.0 No README data
\
> mean@0.4.2 postinstall /projects/fast-annonces
> node node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall


module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '/projects/fast-annonces/node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3

npm ERR! Linux 3.14.27-1-ARCH
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! mean@0.4.2 postinstall: `node node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall`
npm ERR! Exit status 8
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the mean@0.4.2 postinstall script 'node node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mean package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mean
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /projects/fast-annonces/npm-debug.log
```

This is a nightmare!! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I guess you did not have the make tools available when you installed your mongodb library. I suggest you do
Mac:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential
```

and run

```
rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install
```

You need python 2 for it to compile. If your path to python is for python 3 then do this :

```
npm config -g set python "/usr/bin/python2"
```

The 'EACCES` error means the program did not have enough privileges to do what is trying to.

From what I read about groups [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/users_and_groups), you need to add the user to the group `wheel`. Use this command :

```
gpasswd -a [user] [group]
```

Follow the link for a detailed understanding of groups and users.

Comment: I already read this answer from you, but I have arch linux not ubuntu. sudo doesnt work... and build essential doesnt exists

Comment: on Arch : `pacman -S kernel26-headers file base-devel abs` should do the trick.

Comment: Go through [makepkg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/makepkg) usage section to know more about building packages on install

Comment: I am not familiar with this at all... and it asks me this: :: There are 4 providers available for kernel26-headers:
:: Repository core
   1) linux-headers-d3plug  2) linux-headers-sun5i  3) linux-headers-sun5i-staging
   4) linux-sun4i-headers

Comment: I choose option 1, did rm -rf node_modules
npm cache clean
npm install ----> still the same problem..

Comment: also I have this log with npm install : > bson@0.2.16 install /projects/mean/node_modules/bson
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

npm WARN cannot run in wd mean@0.4.2 node node_modules/meanio/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-postinstall (wd=/projects/mean)

Comment: I edited with some more infos... I tried many things yesterday (remove all, reinstall all etc....) Stil not working.

Comment: You need `python2` for it to compile. See answer.

Comment: Here is a description of what I did step by step: https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/1009

Comment: Solved: npm install -g node-gyp
npm install -g browserify

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, All the above answers are only half right.. Took a long time to figure this out..

Mongoose bson install via npm throws warning and causes the error...

```
npm install -g node-gyp

git clone https://github.com/mongodb/js-bson.git
cd js-bson
npm install
node-gyp rebuild
```

This works like magic!!

Comment: in which directory are you performing these steps?

Comment: node-gyp is installed globally, whereas js-bson in node_modules of root app folder and node_modules/mongoose/node_modules

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this command

> apt-get install nodejs-legacy

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu 14.04 I needed to create a link in /usr/bin because /usr/bin/env was looking for /usr/bin/node

ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

The error messages can be found in the builderror.log in each directory so for the message:

bson@0.2.21 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
look at this file for more information about the exact problem

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/bson/builderror.log