# Error: Module did not self-register

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, npm-install

Have tried all the documented fixes I could find: `npm update`, `npm rebuild`, manually removed node_modules folder as well as `rm -r node_modules` then `npm install` or `meteor npm install --save bcrypt`, and `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh`. Still getting:

```
20160927-14:57:19.627(-7)? [Error: Module did not self-register.]
W20160927-14:57:20.974(-7)? (STDERR) js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

Node 4.5.0 / meteor 1.4.1.1 / mac os 10.11.6

Any other ideas greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are missing essential `make` build tools - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27838202/2020002

Comment: Ran `xcode-select --install`, `rm -rf node_modules`, `npm cache clean`, `npm install`. Got `npm WARN  package.json No README data` and `clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9
bcrypt@0.8.7 node_modules/bcrypt
├── bindings@1.2.1
└── nan@2.3.5
`

Comment: Looks like you're all good to go now

Comment: This is so frustrating. When I run `meteor` I still get: `I20160927-18:07:28.690(-7)? [Error: Module did not self-register.]
W20160927-18:07:29.383(-7)? (STDERR) js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version` Thank you for checking back in Derek.

Comment: Downgraded back to Meteor 1.3.2.4 and all is well again.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uncaught Error: Module did not self-register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486891/uncaught-error-module-did-not-self-register)